# Whole word match in JavaScript in an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked high and low for this, with no real idea how to do it now... my scenario:

```
 var strArray = ['Email Address'];

 function searchStringInArray(str, strArray) {
     for (var j = 0; j < strArray.length; j++) {
        if (strArray[j].match(str)) return j;
     }
     return -1;
 }

 var match = searchStringInArray('Email', strArray);
```

Email does NOT equal Email Address... however .match() seems to match the two up, when it shouldn't. I want it to match the exact string. Anyone have any idea how I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for the same thing you are trying to do.

So rather than looping over, why not use:

```
 var match = strArray.indexOf('Email');
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.match` is treating your parameter 'Email' as if it is a regular expression. Just use `==` instead:

```
      if (strArray[j] == str) return j;
```

From the [Mozilla Development Network page on String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> If a non-RegExp object obj is passed, it is implicitly converted to a
>   RegExp by using new RegExp(obj)

Comment: Not even sure why I didn't think of that... too long looking at the code I think! Thanks a lot, that works. I'll accept the answer when I can.

Comment: To be honest, although I've answered your specific question, other answers here are actually closer to what you should be doing. I'm happy to forgo the points in favour of a better answer being promoted.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively using RegExp

Use `^` and `$`

```
var str = "Email";
new RegExp(str).test("Email address")
```

Result: true

And for this:

```
var str = "Email";
new RegExp("^" + str + "$").test("Email address")
```

Result: false